# Critical points of the given system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

> Classify the critical points associated with the Hamiltonian:
>   $$H(p,q)=\frac{p^2}{2}+p \sin q.$$

The Hamiltonian equations are:
$$\dot{p}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}=-p \cos q,~~\dot{q}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}=p+\sin q.$$
Critical points are given by:
$$\dot{p}=0 \implies p=0, q=\left( n+\frac{1}{2} \right) \pi$$
and
$$\dot{q}=0 \implies p+\sin q=0.$$
When $p=0,$ $q=n \pi$ ; when $q=\left( n+\frac{1}{2} \right) \pi,$ $p=\mp 1.$

I need help in continuing here on ward and classify the critical points and sketching them. Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sketch your phase portrait quite nicely with the 'pplane' command in MATLAB. Another way is this nice online tool: http://comp.uark.edu/~aeb019/pplane.html

In your case you get this nice plot

[image]

You can see that your stable fixed points are not asymptotically stable. This is quite typical for Hamiltonian systems since these orbits around a stable critical point behave periodic like 'circles'. This can be seen as the Hamiltonian gives you a Lyapunov function that gives you stability but NOT asymptotic stability.

For example let's take the fixed point $(1,-\pi/2)$  as seen in the plot. It is stable but not asymptotically stable as the other orbits in the neighborhood don't move towards this fixed point.

We have $$
Df(p,q) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-\cos(q) & p \sin(q) \\ 
1 & \cos(q)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and at the equilibrium $(1,-\pi/2)$ we get

$$
Df\left(1,-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &  -1 \\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with eigenvalues $\pm i$. These are non-hyperbolic fixed points since their real part is zero and stability can't be seen immediately. For this we introduce the concept of Lyapunov functions. But before this have a look at some unstable fixed point. For example  as seen in the plot $(0,0)$. You have $$
Df\left(0,0\right) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &  0 \\ 
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$ and therefore the eigenvalues $-1$ and $1$. Since one eigenvalue has positive real part we get that $(0,0)$ is unstable. You see stability of hyperbolic equilibria are quite easy to compute.

Now, back to our non-hyperbolic fixed point.

> **Theorem (Lyapunov functions):** Let $\dot x=f(x)$ s.t. $f$ is a $C^1$ vector field und $f(x_e)=0$ given. Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a nbh of $x_e$. If a function $V \in C^1(U, \mathbb{R})$ exists, which fulfills
>   \begin{equation}
> \begin{cases}
> V(x_e)=0 \\
> V(x)>0 &\text{for } x \in U\backslash\{x_e\}  \\
> \left\langle \nabla V(x),f(x)\right\rangle = 0 &\text{for } x \in U\backslash\{x_e\} 
> \end{cases} \label{lyapunov}
> \end{equation}
>   then $x_e$ is stable in the sense of Lyapunov but not asymptotically stable. Call $V$ Lyapunov function.
>
> So, it can be already seen that Hamiltonians are a good choice for Lyapunov functions. Let $f(p,q)=(\dot p, \dot q)$ and $f(p_e,q_e)=0$. The Hamiltonian has the useful property $$\left\langle \nabla H(p,q),f(p,q) \right\rangle = \left \langle \binom{H_{p}(p,q)}{H_{q}(p,q)}, \binom{\dot p}{\dot q} \right \rangle=0$$ 
>   i.e. the third property for a Lyapunov function is automatically fulfilled. For some constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$ you have
>       $$\nabla(H(p,q)+C)=\nabla H(p,q),$$ and therefore $C$ is arbitrary. It can be chosen such that $H(p_e,q_e)=0$ So let's formulate a theorem that gives the last missing property for a Lyapunov function.
>
> **Theorem:** Let $f(p,q)=(\dot p,\dot q)=(H_q(p,q),-H_p(p,q))$ and $f(p_e,q_e)=0$. If $H$ has a strict local minimum at $(p_e,q_e)$ then $(p_e,q_e)$ is stable in the sense of Lyapunov but not asymptotically stable.
>
> So, all we need to do is checking if the equilibrium is a strict local minimum of $H$ since therefore $H(p,q) > 0$ for $(p,q) \in U \backslash \{(p_e,q_e) \}$ i.e. the second property.

So let's take $H(x,y)=\frac{p^2}{2}+p\sin(q)+C$ and choose $C$ such that $H(1,-\pi/2)=\frac{1}{2}-1+C=0$ i.e. $C=\frac{1}{2}$.

Since $$\nabla H\left(1,-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\binom{p+\sin(q)}{p\cos(q)}\bigg|_{(1,-\frac{\pi}{2})}=\binom{0}{0} \hspace{0.1cm}$$ $$\text{D}^2 H\left(1,-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & \cos(q)  \\
 \cos(q) & -p\sin(q) 
 \end{pmatrix}\bigg|_{(1,-\frac{\pi}{2})}=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0  \\
 0 & 1 
 \end{pmatrix}$$

and therefore your Hessian is positiv definite and $(1,-\pi/2)$ is strict local minimum. By our theorem above $(1,-\pi/2)$ is a stable (but not asymptotically stable) equilibrium of your system.

Since I mentioned this is typical for Hamiltonian systems I also want to mention the famous Duffing-oscillator. It is described by the system

$$\binom{\dot x}{\dot y}=\binom{ y}{x-x^3} $$

with the Hamiltonian $H(x,y)=\frac{1}{2} y^2 - \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \frac{1}{4} x^4$. You will get $(\pm 1,0)$ are stable (but not asymp.) fixed points and $(0,0)$ is unstable (instability follows immediately by looking at the eigenvalues of the Jacobian.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I wanted to do the problem by hand, just wanted to know the available tools to visualize the phase portrait.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint on how to proceed.

You can write the ODE as 
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \begin{pmatrix} p \\ q\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} -p \cos(q) \\ p+ \sin(q) \end{pmatrix} := F(p,q).
$$
We then compute 
$$
DF(p,q) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-\cos(q) & p \sin(q) \\ 
1 & \cos(q)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now plug in the critical points you found in order to find the eigenvalues of $DF$ at the points.  The eigenvalues will allow you to classify the stability of the critical points.